# Format created_at date in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following

`{journal.createdAt}`

`2019-10-30T14:01:59.689Z`

Which is outputting the `created_at` date.

How do I go about formatting this?

I've given this a shot but I think I have the value in the wrong place

```js
{new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: '2-digit'
}).format(journal.createdAt)}
```

I'm getting

```
RangeError: date value is not finite in DateTimeFormat.format()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to ES2015, [`Intl.DateTimeFormat.format(date)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/format) expects the `date` parameter to be a number representing the number of milliseconds since epoch. However, in the MDN docs examples and my own testing on recent Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, those browsers will also accept a `Date` object.

Since the `journal.createdAt` is presumably an ISO8601-formatted string, you can use [`Date.parse(journal.createdAt)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) or `new Date(journal.createdAt)` and pass the resulting value to `Intl.DateTimeFormat.format`, although the former is the way to do it according to the specifications.

[Working example](https://codepen.io/HackedByChinese/pen/yLLPyzK).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", {
          year: "numeric",
          month: "long",
          day: "2-digit"
        });

  render() {
    const dateString = "2019-10-30T14:01:59.689Z";

    return (
      <div>
        Using <code>Date.parse</code>: {this.formatter.format(Date.parse(dateString))}
        <br />
        <em>OR</em>
        <br />
        Using <code>new Date</code>: {this.formatter.format(new Date(dateString))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, so this does work, however, when I'm passing state like `Date.parse(this.state.journal.createdAt)` I get the error

Comment: @nightcode— [*Date.parse*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) returns a number, the [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) of the parsed string. So you might do `new Date(Date.parse(string))`, which is a long winded way of writing `new Date(string)` (the exact same parser is used for both).

Comment: @nightcode I made a mistake describing the `date` param for `format`. I've updated my answer for clarity. Not sure why `Date.parse` didn't work for you, perhaps there was a problem with the value of the field in your test.

Comment: For those having issues with Safari, this is why.